# How do I enable VerifyCsrfToken for some tests?

Tags: php, laravel, automated-tests, csrf-protection

Laravel by default [disables](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v5.3.24/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php#L61) `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware if running tests. As a result I didn't notice that api routes need csrf token to succeed. Is there a way to enable it back for some tests? Like

```
function withVerifyCsrfTokenMiddleware()
{
    $this->app...   // here we're passing something to the app
}
```

And make amendments in `VerifyCsrfToken`'s `handle` method. In a custom one. The one, that overrides the method from the framework. But that's just my idea. Any better ones?

Comment: Which version of laravel are you using?

Comment: @tomirons Laravel 5.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here's what I did:

`app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`:

```
function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $dontSkipCsrfVerificationWhenRunningTests
        = $this->app->bound('dontSkipCsrfVerificationWhenRunningTests')
            && $this->app->make('dontSkipCsrfVerificationWhenRunningTests');
    if (
        $this->isReading($request) ||
        ! $dontSkipCsrfVerificationWhenRunningTests && $this->runningUnitTests() ||
        $this->shouldPassThrough($request) ||
        $this->tokensMatch($request)
    ) {
        return $this->addCookieToResponse($request, $next($request));
    }

    throw new TokenMismatchException;
}
```

`tests/TestCase.php`:

```
function withVerifyCsrfTokenMiddleware()
{
    $this->app->instance('dontSkipCsrfVerificationWhenRunningTests', TRUE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

small change to the answer above, rather than changing the handle method I updated the runningUnitTests method to reduce the chance of an issue on upgrade:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
    ];

    /**
     * Determine if the application is running unit tests.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function runningUnitTests()
    {
        $dontSkip
        = $this->app->bound('dontSkipCsrfVerificationWhenRunningTests')
        && $this->app->make('dontSkipCsrfVerificationWhenRunningTests');

        return $this->app->runningInConsole() && $this->app->runningUnitTests() && !$dontSkip;
    }
}
```